# How to create two separate blog post pages in word-press

Tags: php, wordpress

I have website with blog and cases pages, like example.com/blog and example.com/cases, currently I have installed two wordpress with dedicated databases for both, is this right way?? Is there is any option for creating two blog post pages, I dont want to show cases post in blog section ans blog section posts in cases, both are different, when user viewing it should be under subdirectory. like example.com/blog/post-1 and example.com/cases/post-23.

There is any way to merge database atleast?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible to fulfill your required in single WordPress installation. Leave your blog section as it is. And create a new custom post type named "cases" and post all cases through this custom post type. And create WP page named "cases" for listing all the cases. And create "single-cases.php" page to display single cases individually.

Comment: Thanks, its working, How can i list posts in cases page I want to show recent 5 posts like blog section

Comment: For recent posts I will update the code as soon as possible

Comment: I have added code for the recent posts, please check it out. If you face any difficulties feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying recent 5 posts in your "Cases" page. Create one new cases.php page and put the below line of codes in this PHP page and put it inside your theme directory. And assign the page template for "Cases" WordPress page.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Cases */
$args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'cases' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
    );
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="smal-sec">
        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
        <?php the_content();?>
    </div>
<?php
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```